# Finding SQL Query Bottleneck

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL. To sharpen my skills, I've found a SQL puzzle on Coderloop.com. (Great website for programming puzzles, btw). I am currently working through this puzzle:

http://www.coderloop.com/puzzles/university

I am very close to a solution. I just need to optimize my code. The puzzle requires you to design a course catalog database, along with queries like "add a student to a course" or "get course details". I have, what I think, is a working solution.  I have tested it with my own data, and it seems to perform fine. But Coderloop uses thousands of queries to stress test my database schema and queries. Unfortunately, my solution fails due to a timeout after about 4 minutes or so. I have reviewed my schema and queries and I can't find the bottleneck. Any ideas on how to redesign my database or queries to speed things up?

Notes:

- Executes on a MySQL Server
- The **?s** are parameters of test data passed by the Coderloop bot. See the very bottom of this [page](http://www.coderloop.com/puzzles/university).

**My Soultion**

*Setup Database*

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (
    sid int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255),
    surname varchar(255),
    email varchar(255),
    faculty varchar(255),
    matriculation int,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid)
    );

CREATE INDEX stu_index ON students (sid);   
CREATE TABLE professors (
    pid int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255),
    surname varchar(255),
    email varchar(255),
    faculty varchar(255),
    telephone varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (pid)
);
CREATE INDEX pro_index ON professors (pid); 
CREATE TABLE courses (
    course_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pid int,
    credits int,
    subject varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (course_name)
);
CREATE INDEX cou_index ON courses (course_name);    
CREATE TABLE enrollment (
    course_name varchar(255),
    sid int
);
```

*Add a new professor*

```
INSERT INTO professors (name, surname, email, faculty, telephone, pid)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

*Add a new student*

```
INSERT INTO students (name, surname, email, faculty, matriculation, sid)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

*Add a new course*

```
INSERT INTO courses (course_name, subject, credits)  VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

*Add an existing professor to an existing course*

(This crazy syntax is to match the order of paramaters passed to the ?s)

```
Update courses Set pid = Case When course_name = ? Then ? Else pid End;
```

*Add an existing student to an existing course*

```
INSERT INTO enrollment (course_name, sid) VALUES (?, ?);
```

*Get list of students attending a course*

```
SELECT name, surname FROM students JOIN enrollment ON students.sid=enrollment.sid WHERE course_name=?;
```

*Get professor owning a course*

```
SELECT name, surname, professors.pid FROM professors JOIN courses ON professors.pid=courses.pid WHERE course_name=?;
```

*Get course details*

```
SELECT subject, credits FROM courses WHERE course_name=?;
```

*Get professor details*

```
SELECT name, surname, email, faculty FROM professors WHERE pid=?;
```

*Get student details*

```
SELECT name, surname, email, faculty, matriculation FROM students WHERE sid=?;
```

*Remove a student from a course*

```
DELETE FROM enrollment WHERE sid=? AND course_name=?;
```

*Replace a professor in a course*

```
UPDATE courses SET pid=? WHERE course_name=?;
```

Comment: no indexes or primary keys?  That could cause a problem if there is enough data put into the system...

Comment: I think you might need to rethink the "Add an existing professor to an existing course" section. The site says the parameters are 'course name' and 'ssn', so the query should probably look up the professor by SSN and then update the course from that.

Answer (score 1):

Add indexes on the primary and foreign key fields. That will help quite a bit.

Also, make sure you have indexes on fields involved in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses (in addition to the FK fields)

Ultimately: You are probably going to need to narrow it down to which specific queries are the ones performing slowly so you can focus your efforts there.

Comment: I added primary keys and indexes, but it still fails. (See edit above)

Comment: Can you isolate which one of those queries is chewing up all the time using the query profiler? That would at least help you narrow down the problem scope.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the output of the stress test so I can't narrow the query down. I've tried running a few single queries but all of them return in less than 0.0005 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need

```
CREATE INDEX enr_coursename ON enrollment(course_name);
CREATE INDEX co_pid ON courses(pid);
```